# When can one U.S. agency ask for intelligence or information from another U.S. agency?

Tags: united-states, fbi, intelligence, cia, intelligence-service

When can one U.S. agency ask for intelligence or information from another U.S. agency? Let's say the FBI needs intelligence of information the CIA might have about a certain individual. Can the FBI request it and under what circumstances can they do that?

Comment: relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One situation is an executive order from the President to for example order the CIA to send information on a foreign enemy that is in the country to the FBI to use their domestic law enforcement officers to arrest them.

This could be done in several other ways

1. The President requesting the information from the CIA then sending it to the FBI
2. Ordering the information to be declassified for select members of another agency and telling them how to access it (https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/trump-legal-authority-declassify-intelligence/story?id=47436559).